# Cannot Import F2PY Generated Module in __init__.py

Tags: python, distutils, f2py

I am Wrapping a fortran library with `f2py`, so far it has been successful in terms of getting the functions to work within python

I am at the point of structuring my package and am running into `__init__.py` issues when using these `f2py` generated modules. This is related to a package constructed with `distutils` extensions for `f2py`

After installing the egg, in an external script I can import the `f2py` generated module directly

```
from package.core.module1 import fortran_fn
```

,but when I place

```
from module1 import fortran_fn
```

in  `package/core/__init__.py` in order to refactor the namespace for users,

the package import fails

```
----> 1 import package.core as core
~/venv/dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/package-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/package/core/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 
      2
----> 3 from module1 import fortran_fn
      4
      5 

ImportError: No module named 'module1'
```

*However,* there is one exception, for whatever reason one module in particular, does wish to import itself.

---

### Project Structure:

```
setup.py
package/
  __init__.py
  core/
    __init__.py
    module1.pyf
    module2.pyf
    ...
src/
  lib/
    module1.f
    module2.f
    ...
```

`*pyf` were generated with `f2py -h package/core/moduleX.pyf src/lib/moduleX.f -m moduleX`

Further,

```
#core/__init__.py 

from module1 import fortran_fn
```

and,

```
#setup.py
from setuptools import find_packages
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension


ext1 = Extension(name='package.core.module1', 
                 sources=['package/core/module1.pyf',
                 'src/lib/module1.f'])
#ext2 = ...
# and others

setup (name="package",
       packages = find_packages(),
       ext_modules = [ ext1 ]) # ..., ext2, ... ]
```

Code samples simplified to illustrate the problem, the specific code is available at [this github](https://github.com/nc5ng/nadcon5-ng/tree/develop/f2py-wrapper-integration-01)

---

For some context, I initially tried to have `f2py` place the fortran into the `.core` subpackage directly by compiling with `-m package.core` and the same for `name='package.core'` for extension, however `f2py` would complain about missing names.

In this particular structure there is an additional layer where each fortran module is just one function, and I would like to remove the extra submodule layer from the API.

Answer (score 1):

Using a fully qualified name in `core/__init__.py` will resolve the immediate import problem.

Instead of:

```
#core/__init__.py

from module1 import fortran_fn
```

This will work:

```
#core/__init__.py

from package.core.module1 import fortran_fn
```

then

```
> import package.core as c
> c.fortran_fn()
 SUCCESS
```

It appears the `f2py` extensions do not register as subpackages/submodules when `distutils` runs. I may be mistaken in that interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 all imports are absolute. To perform relative import do it explicitly:

```
from .module1 import fortran_fn
```

Comment: Thank you, root cause was me not paying attention to this particular `py3` change. I wonder why, when using import incorrectly, was there one package that made it though the import